# Macro for sum up numeric of a single cell

Tags: excel, vba

need to add all the numbers in each cell to a single number.

Example: I have a cell that has "17.23455" in it; I would like to add all of the numbers in the cell to get a single number.... 1+7+2+3+4+5+5 = 27 and 2+ 7 = 9. So the value i'm looking for is 9.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
=1+MOD(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"@"),".","")-1,9)
```

[image]

Or with VBA:

```
Dim result as Long
result = ((CLng(Replace(Cstr(ActiveSheet.Range("A1")),".","")) - 1) Mod 9) + 1
Debug.Print result
```

One note: as RonRosenfeld pointed out this formula only works for numbers greater than 0.  If 0 is an option then we need to wrap the formula in an IF:

```
=IF(A1=0,0,1+MOD(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"@"),".","")-1,9))
```

Comment: Nice formula, except `0` => `9`

Comment: Yes, theoretically this only works for numbers >0.  For `0` we can wrap in an if: `IF(A1=0,0,1+MOD(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"@"),".","")-1,9))`

Comment: I'd probably just add a caveat to the answer. I hadn't thought about that as a solution to digit summing in the past, so it was really interesting to see.